# How to save a jpegtran JPEG in a numpy same as with PIL?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library, caffe

I have started using a new library in my Python program to process images due to speed. I was using PIL but now I am using jpegtran. My previous code I would save the image to a numpy array and that worked perfectly fine, but now since the datatype is different I am having problems creating the same numpy array.

PIL code:

```
 In[1]: import numpy
 In[2]: from PIL import Image
 In[3]: image = Image.open('43.jpg')
 In[4]: image
Out[4]: <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=3216x2136 at 0x7F34CC1876C8>
 In[5]: imgArray2 = numpy.asarray(image, dtype=numpy.float32)
 In[6]: imgArray2.shape
Out[6]: (2136, 3216, 3)
```

jpegtran code:

```
 In[1]: import numpy
 In[2]: from jpegtran import JPEGImage
 In[3]: imgTran = JPEGImage('43.jpg')
 In[4]: imgTran
Out[4]: <jpegtran.transform.JPEGImage at 0x7f34d58a9910>
 In[5]: imgArray = numpy.asarray(imgTran.data, dtype=numpy.float32)
 In[6]: imgArray.shape
Out[6]: (777062,)
```

I need the original shape (2136, 3216, 3) for it to work with the rest of my code.

Comment: Have you tried the reshape command?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: I did not try this because when I first multiplied 2136*3216*3 = 20608128, so it's not the same size. I feel the solution lies in how PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile is different from jpegtran.transform.JPEGImage.
I also got ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged.